# What do multiples of 100 represent in "return date"?

Tags: php, json

For example, what would this represent:

```
return date( 'Hi' ) >= '500' && date( 'Hi' ) <= '900';
```

Comment: RTLM? http://php.net/date

Comment: Output this date('H:i') and it will be clear, what represents what.

Comment: Few points of advice:
* Do not use string as integers. You will hate yourself when debuging
* Use \DateTime[1] for dealing with dates.
[1] http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`date('H')` is the hour in 24 hour format, whereas `i` is the minutes.  500 is 5:00am and 900 is 9:00am, so the system time must be between 5:00am and 9:00am